# Show or hide subscription form upon click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, onclick

I have the following subscribe form:

```
<div class="AW-Form-2026756516"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "http://forms.aweber.com/form/16/2026756516.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, "script", "aweber-wjs-kocxshsyj"));
</script>
```

I would like this to show or hide when the user clicks Subscribe button (Possibly dropdown effect or basic).

```
<div id="subscribe"><a href="">Subscribe</a></div>
```

Many thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#subscribe').click(function(){
   $('.AW-Form-2026756516').slideToggle(); // or fadeToggle() or just toggle()
});
```